# Unix Shell finding unique rows based on muliple columns

Tags: shell, unix, unique

I'm trying to find the unique rows based on multiple columns but my code does not seem to work. Or at least it managed to remove almost all duplicate.

```
1    A
2    B
3    C
1    A
2    A
3    B
2    A
3    C
1    C
1    A
2    A
3    B
```

This is the code that I tried

```
sort -k1 -k2 TEST.txt | awk -F"\t" '!seen[$1, $2]++'
```

Expected output:

```
1    A
1    C
2    A
2    B
3    B
3    C
```

But output I get:

```
1    A
1    C
2    A
2    B
3    B
3    B
3    C
```

I still have the duplicate of `3    B` in my output. Can anyone help? Is something wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sort -u` to sort and get unique result:

```
sort -u file

1    A
1    C
2    A
2    B
3    B
3    C
```

Using `awk` you can do this:

```
awk '!seen[$1,$2]++' file | sort
```

Comment: My last data which is `3    B` is different from the rest. Its just `3^IB` while the rest have `^M$` as the back. Mind explaining?

Comment: Check your input file with `cat -A file` command and post it's output in question.